# How do I put multiple links on the same line? (HTML5)

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm trying to put multiple links on the same line so I can have a whole bar of links, I've tried this:

```
<a href="website_homepage.htm"><h2 style="font-family:tempus sans itc;">Home</h2></a> <a     href="website_hills.htm"><h2 style="font-family:tempus sans itc;">Hills Pupil Tailored Website</h2></a>
```

but when I test to see if it works, these two links are on seperate lines, does anyone know how I can get them on the same line?

Comment: `h2 { display: inline }`

Comment: That's invalid; `h2` is a block element, whilst `a` is inline...

Comment: @TiesonT., no, [the `a` element has a transparent content model, which allows it to contain flow content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: @zzzzBov The 4.01 spec says it's inline: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2, although the HTML5 spec agrees with your WHATWG link: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a - so I suppose it depends on doctype.

Comment: @TiesonT., you should note that this post was tagged with  [tag:html5]

Comment: @zzzzBov Fair enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply add:

```
h2{
    display: inline;
}
```

To your CSS and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 6):

That's because of `h2` `display` property which is `block`.

Try with:

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

at the beginning of your file (enclosed by `<style>` tags) or in your stylesheet file.

See *Typical default display properties* [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively replace "h2" with for example "span" and the links will be on the same line.
or you could put:

```
<h2 style="font-family:tempus sans itc;"><a href="website_homepage.htm">Home</a> <a href="website_hills.htm">Hills Pupil Tailored Website</a></h2>
```

Putting all the links within one h2 tag instead of using one for each link.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this in just HTML, if that's what you're looking for. If you re-write your code to look like this:

```
<a href="website_homepage.htm">Home</a>
<a href="website_hills.htm">Hills Pupil Tailored Website</a>
```

Then your links will show side by side.

Full transparency, I'm just starting out on my developer journey. I'm currently taking a full stack developer course and I'm just on the HTML section of the course (I haven't hit the css or javascript portion of it yet). So there may be a better way to do it using CSS or other tricks that I haven't learned yet.

I'm assuming I'll eventually learn how to format this through CSS but I figured I'd add what I know in case it's what you're looking for.

Comment: This loses the properties of h2 that OP was probably looking for