# Multiple href urls to make a single line in HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

```js
function openinnewtab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-heading">
  <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#190000">
    <strong>
         You agree to my <a href="#" onclick="javescript:openinnewtab('www.example.com')">Terms and conditions.</a>
      </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is , HTML is not coming in a single line/sentence.Its coming to a new line after "". That is the url "www.example.com" is coming in a new line.

How can I make this in a single line: "You agree to my Terms and conditions." ?
Is there any way to add HTML inside CSS to make this work?

Note: basically the idea is to open the "www.example.com" url in a new tab.This is what I have tried as well : https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/51

****Edit****

How its now coming :

```
 You agree to my 
 Terms and conditions
```

The expected result should be (in a single line):

```
  You agree to my Terms and conditions
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use ```target="_blank"``` for this purpose? And it may CSS issue. Anchor tag is an inline element. It renders in a same line with text.

Comment: Firstly, there's no apostrophe in Terms and Conditions. Secondly, an apostrophe, where needed, would have a special html charcode. (apostrophe is `&#39;`)

Comment: also you have an excess quote mark after font-family. (it should just be "font-family:  etc ; color:etc; "

Comment: Thanks.I just typed it quickly and Corrected the things as suggested. Added: You agree to my <a href="#" onclick="javescript:openinnewtab('www.example.com')" target ="_blank" >Terms and conditions.</a>   . Took the ref here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917922/how-do-i-put-multiple-links-on-the-same-line-html5  . Still having problem. Any clue?

Comment: @AskMe what do you mean you're "still having problems"? Please edit your question to clarify what the issue is. If the issue is that your js isn't working then i suggest you edit your title or ask a new question.

Comment: @RachelGallen edited my question, Hope it is now more clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AskMe I can't reproduce the wrapping issue - it came up on one line when I put it jsfiddle now. That might be a css sub-heading /width issue on the paragraph or link. However, I do have a working sample.. you might need to fix the width thing yourself

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't demonstrate the problem. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AskMe https://jsfiddle.net/xkfjug7n/ for what it's worth. I appended a http to the url in the function. (I also took out the unnecessary "javascript: " before the function name. Besides there was a typo in it, at least in the post (it was spelt javescript) )

Comment: @RachelGallen  Is there any way to make this in one line without using sub-heading? Please let me know. I'm OK if I don't use class="sub-heading" OR Should I create a new css class as per my fit.

Comment: I don't know your CSS so I can't say definitely. Maybe make a new class. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Missing protocol. http or https. You can add `javascript:void 0` in href, if you dont want to change hash.

```js
function openinnewtab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-heading">
  <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#190000">
    <strong>
         You agree to my <a href="javascript:void 0" onclick="openinnewtab('https://www.google.com/')">Terms and conditions.</a>
      </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, it looks there are issues related to css. I used the same css, which is working fine for another sentence in the web page.Note: I'm including "sub-heading"  css in between other two css class. I think that is the problem. Will try some ways to adjust css. The page is designed such a manner that , I need to put this terms & condition sentence in between "username,password" and "submit" button. This user name password and submit button having their own css. Hope I have clarified it properly.

Comment: More over , could you please clarify more on this "Missing protocol. http or https. You can add javascript:void 0 in href, if you dont want to change hash." and how its different than my implementation ?

Comment: when u add hash in href, it is like changing state or pushing # into history state. you can see it on url. `javascript: void 0` is to avoid that. while passing domain url you missed `http/https`. specifying protocal.

Comment: I just took out my css outside the nested css. Still there is a problem. I think, HTML does not provide the way to join lines ( the way I'm implementing it). Just added few tags with question change. Hope someone has some some clue to fix this?

Comment: it is comming as single line to me.. i tested.. check my answer for image

Comment: Is it issue with Visual Studio 2015? I believe Microsoft has always something to fix. Microsoft needs to take this positively.Any tag in HTML to join the line for the way I am doing? I know we have </br> as line break.