# How can I place multiple href links in one line using html?

Tags: html, css, href

Right now my h1 text is display each href on it's own line. I tried `h1 {display: inline;}` but it's not working. How can I put them all in one line? Thanks

```
<h1>Most recently built <a href="https://test.com" target="_blank">Test</a>, <a href="https://test.com/" target="_blank">Test2</a>, and Test3.</h1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put multiple links on the same line? (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917922/how-do-i-put-multiple-links-on-the-same-line-html5)

Comment: @Christian no because diplay: inline or inline-block are not working as I mentioned

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue though. Sorry for not being a help.

Comment: The code you've provided works fine, please include more code so we can identify your issue

Comment: @Christian no worries I'm using an exported code so it may be the problem, but of course there must be a solution

Comment: @ZachJensz I originally exported code from webflow and have been coding on it to save money. I've also been self teaching myself code. The folder has 3 CSS codes I found h1 in each and added display: inline. Does this help?

Comment: That doesn't really help, would still be trying to find waldo with half the page torn off

Comment: If you post more code, I can look through it with you for whatever styles are overriding your elements

Comment: @ZachJensz Thank you. How can I share code on vscode when it's multiple files and each of the three CSS is 300+ lines? I see there's a liveshare option, but not sure if it works for you via stackoverflow

Comment: Here's the parent div ---
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="intro-wrap"><strong class="bold-text">Hey <strong> I&#x27;m Aaa</strong>! I love building & growing products. <br></strong>
        <h1 class="heading-jumbo">Most recently built <a href="https://test.com" target="_blank">test</a>, <a href="https://test.com/" target="_blank">tester</a>, and test.<br></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: I'd prefer you [Make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you're unable to produce one, copy paste your code into a expandable snippet in your question.

Comment: I copied all the files into replit and realized the 3rd stylesheet was the issue. Then I noticed out of the 1k lines there was a a {display: block} code that was causing it. I deleted it and it looks good to go! Thank you for your help!